# NestJS lifecycle events some time is not executed as expected in e2e tests

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I added a service to initialize some sample data when the application is starting and shutting down.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostDataInitializerService
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private data: CreatePostDto[] = [
    {
      title: 'Generate a NestJS project',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Create CRUD RESTful APIs',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Connect to MongoDB',
      content: 'content',
    },
  ];

  constructor(
    @Inject(POST_MODEL) private postModel: Model<Post>,
    @Inject(COMMENT_MODEL) private commentModel: Model<Comment>,
  ) {}

  onModuleInit(): void {
    console.log('(PostModule) is initialized...');
    Promise.all(this.data.map((d) => this.postModel.create(d))).then((saved) =>
      console.log(saved),
    );
  }

  onModuleDestroy(): void {
    Promise.all([
      this.postModel.deleteMany({}),
      this.commentModel.deleteMany({}),
    ]).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

There is a test in the `e2e` to check the number of data, [app.e2e-spec.ts#L26-L30)](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-sample/blob/feat/config/test/app.e2e-spec.ts#L26-L30).

```js
    it('/posts (GET)', async () => {
      const res = await request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/posts').send();
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      expect(res.body.length).toEqual(3);
    });
```

But some times it works, others it does not, the count is not 3 in startups.

```sh
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 3
    Received: 2

      27 |       const res = await request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/posts').send();
      28 |       expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    > 29 |       expect(res.body.length).toEqual(3);
         |                               ^
      30 |     });
```

The failure info in another run.

```sh
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 3
    Received: 1

      27 |       const res = await request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/posts').send();
      28 |       expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    > 29 |       expect(res.body.length).toEqual(3);
         |                               ^
      30 |     });
      31 | 
      32 |     it('/posts (GET) if none existing should return 404', async () => {
```

Comment: Asserting the exact body rather than `length` would probably make assertions more meaningful. From the question itself, it's not easy to follow how PostDataInitializerService affects the result. But in case it does, shouldn't onModuleInit and onModuleDestroy return promises to not cause race conditions?

Comment: What confused me is I was using `await app.init` in `before` hooks, but the `OnModuleInit` is not finished when the tests start to run. So there are partial data loaded of the `get` result in my assert.

Comment: I changed codes to use `insertMany`(batch insert)  in the initializer, it seems most of the time the tests passed.